# Android: How to cover Soft Nav buttons with View using LayoutParams

Tags: android

I have a custom view that adds a variable filter (light effects, etc) over the entire screen. This runs as a service when the main activity is closed, so the user can change apps etc with the filters running.

The code is effectively:

```
EffectsView view = new EffectsView();
WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) service.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    windowManager.addView(view, new Params());

private class Params extends WindowManager.LayoutParams
    {
        public Params()
        {
            super();

            this.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY;
            this.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            this.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            this.flags = 280;
            this.format = PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT;
        }
    }
```

I'm currently using the `flags = 280` parameter as it covers the notification bar, but it doesn't cover the soft nav buttons. This is most noticeable in the App Switcher.

I have tried the using the flag `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN`, but that doesn't cover the nav buttons or the notification bar.

Is there a way to get the view to cover the nav bar area?

Note: my supported SDK versions are 17+